# How change MIDI file?

Tags: java, midi

In [www.jsresources.org](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/CreateSequence.java.html) is example, but still problems:
What is velocity? beats per minute? why not 120 but 64? why ticks means not 1.3 millisecond interval but 0.5 second? How place shorter note? 
How read instruments from file? 
My sample code

```
Synthesizer synthesizer;
synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
synthesizer.open();
MidiChannel chan = synthesizer.getChannels()[0];
chan.programChange(1152, 14);
```

reads MidiChannel from system (global?) not from file.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is the volume or gain of a note. It goes from 0 to 127 - higher the number, louder the note will be.

64 was chosen probably because it is a medium level (not too loud).

To be able to use shorter notes, you will have to change the resolution of your sequence - this is the "tempo based" resolution and works in ticks per quarter note:

```
sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 1);
```

Increasing the second argument, you will have more ticks per quarter note, and consequently shorter notes.

You could also use:

```
sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.SMPTE_30, 1);
```

This would give you a division type of 30 frames per second. The second argument is giving you a maximum resolution of 1 note per frame.

It's all in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Sequence.html).

Here's a sample - modified from your example link - it should save a file on your desktop. You might have to change that to a different location:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiEvent;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage;
import javax.sound.midi.Track;
import javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException;

public class CreateSequence {

    private static final int VELOCITY = 64;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")
                + "//Desktop//file.midi");
        Sequence sequence = null;
        try {
            sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.SMPTE_30, 2);

        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Track track = sequence.createTrack();
        int note = 40;
        for (int tick = 0; tick < 215;) {
            track.add(createNoteEvent(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, ++note, VELOCITY,
                    tick));
            track.add(createNoteEvent(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, note, VELOCITY,
                    tick += 3));
        }

        try {
            MidiSystem.write(sequence, 0, outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static MidiEvent createNoteEvent(int nCommand, int nKey,
            int nVelocity, long lTick) {
        ShortMessage message = new ShortMessage();
        try {
            message.setMessage(nCommand, 0, nKey, nVelocity);
        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        MidiEvent event = new MidiEvent(message, lTick);
        return event;
    }
}
```

Reading from file is a whole new question. Check the docs!